# Not working keyboard after using of InputSimulator (Send input wrapper)

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendinput

I had implemented a remote keyboard.
From the slave side , I inject event with Inputsimulator.
After i close the slave program my keyboard seems to not working,
It receives input,but for example if i press "c"  it get "space" and so on... 
Someone can explain to me why?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe someone here is a psychic and can guess what your code looks like to find the problem...

Comment: hope it...:) sorry i will post the code...

Comment: The code is useless i send an ascii code from master.

And i receive it correctly in the slave.

After i have only a switch that just call inputsimulator() with the code received as parameter...

Comment: Sorry, but then your question is useless too.